# Query for a collection property size using spring-data and QueryDSL

Tags: querydsl, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using spring-data-mongodb:1.2.0.RELEASE and QueryDSL:2.9.0.

I have two classes A and B as follow:

```
@Document(collection = "A")
public class A {
    public BigInteger id;
    public Set<B> bSet;
}

@Document(collection = "B")
public class B {
    public BigInteger id;

}
```

And a repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends MongoRepository<A, BigInteger>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<A>
{

}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get all of the A documents that their b collection size is at a certain size.
So, I'm executing the next query:

```
aRepository.findAll(QA.a.bSet.size().loe(1));
```

and I'm getting:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Illegal operation size(a.bSet)
at com.mysema.query.mongodb.MongodbSerializer.visit(MongodbSerializer.java:204)
at com.mysema.query.mongodb.MongodbSerializer.visit(MongodbSerializer.java:34)
at com.mysema.query.types.expr.NumberOperation.accept(NumberOperation.java:74)
at com.mysema.query.mongodb.MongodbSerializer.asDBValue(MongodbSerializer.java:75)
at com.mysema.query.mongodb.MongodbSerializer.asDBKey(MongodbSerializer.java:71)
at com.mysema.query.mongodb.MongodbSerializer.visit(MongodbSerializer.java:186)
at com.mysema.query.mongodb.MongodbSerializer.visit(MongodbSerializer.java:34)
at com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanOperation.accept(BooleanOperation.java:53)
at com.mysema.query.mongodb.MongodbSerializer.handle(MongodbSerializer.java:39)
at com.mysema.query.mongodb.MongodbQuery.createQuery(MongodbQuery.java:362)
at com.mysema.query.mongodb.MongodbQuery.createCursor(MongodbQuery.java:272)
at com.mysema.query.mongodb.MongodbQuery.createCursor(MongodbQuery.java:267)
at com.mysema.query.mongodb.MongodbQuery.list(MongodbQuery.java:253)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QueryDslMongoRepository.findAll(QueryDslMongoRepository.java:93)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QueryDslMongoRepository.findAll(QueryDslMongoRepository.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy68.findAll(Unknown Source)
at com.shunra.server.test.filesmanagement.TestFilesRepository.tmp(TestFilesRepository.java:248)
```

To sum it up, I need an example/explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported in Querydsl. Feel free to create a ticket on [GitHub](http://www.github.com/mysema/querydsl).

Comment: I'm not sure this was resolved, for your reference I created a new ticket also here: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2057

Comment: I am facing the same issue similar like this but using aggregate .sum().eq(xx)